# 'au.com.dius.pact.provider.gradle.PactVerificationTask' property 'providerToVerify' is missing an input or output annotation

Tags: gradle, jenkins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have upgraded Gradle v6.8 to v8.2.1 for compatibility with JAVA v17. Build is successful in local (IntelliJ) but getting below error in Jenkins build.

```
11:24:59  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:24:59  
11:24:59  * What went wrong:
11:24:59  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':pactVerify_xxx' (type 'PactVerificationTask').
11:24:59    - In plugin 'au.com.dius.pact' type 'au.com.dius.pact.provider.gradle.PactVerificationTask' property 'providerToVerify' is missing an input or output annotation.
11:24:59      
11:24:59      Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
11:24:59      
11:24:59      Possible solutions:
11:24:59        1. Add an input or output annotation.
11:24:59        2. Mark it as @Internal.
```

Cannot find any 'providerToVerify' property or 'PactVerificationTask' class in workspace. Also my "au.com.dius.pact" version is "4.0.3". Please suggest any workaround. Tried upgrading to latest v4.6.1 but still not successful.